# Binding between custom Usercontrol and ViewModel not working in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

I've created a custom usercontrol in my application and I try to bind to its property (BindableProperty) to ViewModel but it doesn't work for me. Am I doing something wrong?
This is the usercontrol. It is just custom stepper for the purpose of test project: "decrease" and "increase" buttons and quantity label between them.
Please notice that binding inside the usercontrol works perfect (for example Commands bindings) . What I am trying to do is bind QuantityProperty to ViewModel

```
namespace UsercontrolBindingTest.Usercontrols
{
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    public class CustomQuantityStepper : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty QuantityProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Quantity), typeof(int), typeof(CustomQuantityStepper), 0, BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public int Quantity
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)base.GetValue(QuantityProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                base.SetValue(QuantityProperty, value);
                this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Quantity));
            }
        }

        public ICommand DecreaseQuantityCommand { get; private set; }

        public ICommand IncreaseQuantityCommand { get; private set; }

        public CustomQuantityStepper()
        {
            this.BindingContext = this;

            this.DecreaseQuantityCommand = new Command(() => this.Quantity--);
            this.IncreaseQuantityCommand = new Command(() => this.Quantity++);

            this.DrawControl();
        }

        private void DrawControl()
        {
            var quantityEntry = new Entry();
            quantityEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("Quantity", BindingMode.TwoWay));
            quantityEntry.WidthRequest = 50;
            quantityEntry.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

            var increaseQuantityButton = new Button { Text = "+" };
            increaseQuantityButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, "IncreaseQuantityCommand");

            var decreaseQuantityButton = new Button { Text = "-" }; 
            decreaseQuantityButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, "DecreaseQuantityCommand");

            var ui = new StackLayout()
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Children =
                {
                    decreaseQuantityButton,
                    quantityEntry,
                    increaseQuantityButton
                }
            };

            this.Content = ui;
        }
    }
}
```

The view with proof that binding between View and VM is working:

```
namespace UsercontrolBindingTest
{
    using Usercontrols;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new ContentPage
            {
                BindingContext = new MainPageVM(),
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children =
                    {
                        this.GetLabel("Title"),
                        this.GetCustomStepper(),
                        this.GetLabel("SelectedQuantity")
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private Label GetLabel(string boundedPropertyName)
        {
            var ret = new Label();
            ret.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            ret.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(boundedPropertyName));

            return ret;
        }

        private CustomQuantityStepper GetCustomStepper()
        {
            var ret = new CustomQuantityStepper();
            var dataContext = this.BindingContext as MainPageVM;

            ret.SetBinding(CustomQuantityStepper.QuantityProperty, new Binding("SelectedQuantity", BindingMode.TwoWay));

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

And my simple ViewModel:

```
namespace UsercontrolBindingTest
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    internal class MainPageVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _selectedQuantity;

        public int SelectedQuantity
        {
            get
            {
                return this._selectedQuantity;
            }

            set
            {
                this._selectedQuantity = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(this.SelectedQuantity));
            }
        }

        public string Title { get; set; } = "ViewModel is bound";

        public MainPageVM()
        {
            this.SelectedQuantity = 0;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked plenty of different topis and blog posts but I wasn't able to find solutions for my issue. Hope for help here...
Attached sample project here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Apu16I9kXJFtl28YBjkfwDztT9j0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `BindingContext` of `CustomQuantityStepper` to itself (`this`). That's why the binding engine is looking for a public property named "SelectedQuantity" in your custom control and *not* in the ViewModel.

- Don't set the `BindingContext` in the control and instead let it use the context that is currently defined and (hopefully) points to the VM.
- Set the `Source` [property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Binding.Source/) of the `Binding` and let it point to the correct source (which would be the VM).